# Using Sidekiq and Twilio to send text message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio, sidekiq

I'm using Twilio and Sidekiq to send text messages at specified times, but am having difficulty finding more exact documentation. Are there any good resources for this, since the wiki and github documentation don't seem to have anything as specific as I need?

Comment: Some details would be helpful.  Are you having problems with scheduling Sidekiq jobs or sending the text messages with Twilio?  Also if you have any code detailing what you are trying to do, that would be helpful as well.  I have a lot of experience using Twilio and Sidekiq.

Comment: @BillWatts , currently the user enters information on a form, including a datetime and a phone number. That number is stored in my database. I then want to use my own twilio phone number, AccountSID and authtoken to send a message to the user at the datetime specified in the form that the user filled out. The closest thing that I have found is [https://github.com/wiseleyb/twilio-test](https://github.com/wiseleyb/twilio-test), but there the user has to include his/her own authtoken and accountsid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the official [twilio gem](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby), it gives you a super easy wrapper to do pretty much every thing you would want to do with twilio.  So your worker would look something like this...

```
require 'twilio-ruby'
class SendSMS
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(record_id)
    record = Collection.find record_id
    @twilio = Twilio::REST::Client.new "[Your Account SID]", "[Your Token]"

    @twilio.account.messages.create(
      from: '[Your Phone Number]',
      to: record.phone_number,
      body: 'Hey there!  This is your reminder.'
    )
  end
end
```

You would then schedule your Sidekiq job like so.

```
SendSMS.perform_at(record.remind_at, record.id)
```

Based on what you outlined above, something similar to this should do it.